# How to log apache thrift request in golang?

Tags: go, thrift

I need write log with apache thrift request. I cant find anything instead of TDebugProtocol, but it cant provide names of fields, only values.
What I expects push to log:

```
serviceName: blabla:blablaMethod
data:
    field1: value1
    field2:
         field1: value1
         field2: value2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "tee" style transport layer with one leg of the tee going to the normal RPC transport and the other going to a logger (like a file transport). Here's an example of a simple Java Tee protocol:

[Java Tee Transport](https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/blob/master/part2/servers/factories/TTeeTransport.java)

If you are using the Json protocol you could log it as is. If not you might want to deserialize the data in the logger or take another road (e.g. wrapping the client).

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same what provides DebugProtocol. We use binary protocol and trouble with logging not fixed =(

Comment: In the transport solution you can deserialize the bin proto data on flush and print it any way you like. If you are using a service mux that would include the "service" name. You could also log the data encoded and then write a simple utility (or fluentd plugin or somesuch) to decode the log in bulk to avoid loading the client proc.

In the client wrapper solution you can print the args directly without messing with the Protocol. You don't seem to be comfortable with the Protocol wrapper option (TDebugProto) so transport/client are the only two other real choices.

Comment: I create pull request to apache, you can like it if you want https://github.com/apache/thrift/pull/1992